# Is it possible to make shared element transition animation from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, shared-element-transition

So I have activity with image and i want to show fragment on top of that activity with image transition to fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final View image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final DetailsFragment kittenDetails = DetailsFragment.newInstance(1);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                kittenDetails.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
                kittenDetails.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
                kittenDetails.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailsTransition());
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .addSharedElement(image, "kittenImage")
                    .replace(R.id.container, kittenDetails)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
}
}
```

But that just not working. If i do the same between two fragments its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not possible with android framework because documentation to addSharedElement says:

> Used with custom Transitions to map a View from a removed or hidden
>      **Fragment**.